# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) when trying to destroy instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting an error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

```
def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params(:id))
    @event.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Event destroyed."
    redirect_to events_path
end
```

i'm trying to destroy an @event and it doesn't work because @event = Event.find(params(:id)) has the wrong number of parameters. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be `params[:id]` instead of `params(:id)`.

Comment: Good catch... I didn't even notice that.